# MVC validating currency format on post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a lot decimal values that I have displayed as `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

I'm using `EditorFor` and the values show as I wish e.g `£250,000.00`.

But when I submit the form `ModelState.IsValid` always euqals `false`, I guess this is because of the comma and £ in the value, is there an easy way around this issue that i'm missing?

Comment: You would need to create your own custom `ModelBinder` to parse the value back to a `decimal`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net MVC 1.0 and 2.0 currency model binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453591/asp-net-mvc-1-0-and-2-0-currency-model-binding)